# Sharepoint 2010 - Object Model - Download DocumentSet Programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-object-model

A code snippet of how i can download a documentSet programmatically using the sharepoint object model would really help.

What I am trying to do is 
- Given the sharepoint site, log in with the user default credentials
- look for the document library where the files are hosted
- Pull the files down on to the local machine

What I have done so far,

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["site"]);
            cc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pwd, domain);
            Web site = cc.Web;
            ListCollection collList = site.Lists;

            var oList = collList.GetByTitle("Document Set test");

            // Get the document set
            cc.Load(oList);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();

            // Get All views
            var views = oList.Views;
            cc.Load(views);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();

            // Get All documents
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<Query>
                                   <ViewFields>
                                        <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                                        <FieldRef Name='Display Name'/>
                                   </ViewFields>
                                   <Where>
                                      <Gt>
                                         <FieldRef Name='Created' />
                                         <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>1900-05-08T14:25:50Z</Value>
                                      </Gt>
                                   </Where>   
                                   <OrderBy>
                                         <FieldRef Name='Title' Ascending='True' />
                                   </OrderBy>                                    
                                </Query>";

            var docs = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            cc.Load(docs);
            cc.ExecuteQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Models in the repository", docs.Count));
```

foreach (var doc in docs)
                {

// DOWNLOAD THE DOCUMENTS in the DOCUMENT SET - BUT HOW?

```
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} => {1} ", Environment.NewLine, doc["Title"]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: I would ask sharepoint.stackexchange.com, you might find more gurus there

Comment: Done, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31218/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-download-documentset-programmatically Any other recommendations?

Comment: msdn forums are good too, if you have not posted it there.

Comment: haha. No hope of getting an answer on stackoverflow? I'll try msdn forum as well.

Answer (score 0):

You will be interested in the [`Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.openbinarydirect.aspx) method. It returns [`FileInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fileinformation.aspx) which makes the content accessible via the [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fileinformation.stream.aspx) property. You can have a look at code examples in [other thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024524/sharepoint-2010-client-object-model-with-camlquery-file-download-but-no-conten), on [an MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524.aspx) or in [a Codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103503/How-to-upload-download-a-document-in-SharePoint-20).

And yes, there are SharePoint developers on Stackoverflow too :-)

--- Ferda